# Box function with 11 elements

Tags: image-processing

There is an image and it is blurred horizontally with an 11 element box filter. My question is: how can the box filter be 11 elements? And since it says horizontal direction here, could it be a kernel 11 element row vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's just a mean filter kernel. Think of it as an 11 element kernel where each coefficient is equal to 1/11. So in effect it sets each output pixel to the average value of the input pixels in the range -5 to +5 in the X axis.

Comment: This kernel is not matrix form right? Only row vector?

Comment: Yes, 11x1 kernel.

Comment: Horizontal direction should be `1 x 11` but Paul is correct.  It's just a 1D kernel with 1 row, and 11 elements.

Comment: Thank you very much guys .